# Add class after componentDidMount in reactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, zurb-foundation

Let's say I have a reactJS component. 
I want to add a class to a couple of elements inside that component.

This is my component's render method;

```
render() {
    var self = this;
        return (
         <div className='mainClass'>
            <div className='class1'>
            <div className='class2'>
            <div className='class3'>
         </div>
        )
   }
```

The elements classes are something like this class1, class2, class3, etc..
Now I want to add an extra class to `<div1>` and `<div2>` after they got loaded.

Right now I'm doing something like this:

Inside my `componentDidMount` function

```
$('.class1,.class2').addClass('extraClass');
```

I also want to add a `foundation accordion` event listener on my mainClass component:
This is what I'm trying to achieve in reactJS:

http://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/vb5rchxn/13/

To add the foundation accordion event listener,
I am doing something like this

```
$('.mainClass').on('toggled', function (event, accordion) {
    console.log('hi');
  if(accordion.parents('li').hasClass('disabled'))
    accordion.removeClass('active');
});
```

I added this in my componeneDidMound but the classes are not getting added.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use jQuery in your ReactJS component you can do something like that https://jsfiddle.net/sumbad/p0kyjnyk/

```
var Hello = React.createClass({

    componentDidMount: function() {
    $(document).foundation('accordion');

    $('body').on('click', '#disable-steps', function(){
    console.log('ee');
      $('.step-1,.step-2').addClass('disabled');
    })

    $('.accordion').on('toggled', function (event, accordion) {
      if(accordion.parents('li').hasClass('disabled'))
        accordion.removeClass('active');
    });
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
     <ul className="accordion" data-accordion="myAccordionGroup">
      <li className="accordion-navigation step-1">
        <a href="#panel1c">Step 1</a>
        <div id="panel1c" className="content">
          Panel 1. Lorem ipsum dolor
        </div>
      </li>
      <li className="accordion-navigation step-2">
        <a href="#panel2c">Step 2</a>
        <div id="panel2c" className="content">
          Panel 2. Lorem ipsum dolor
        </div>
      </li>
      <li className="accordion-navigation step-3">
        <a href="#panel3c">Step 3</a>
        <div id="panel3c" className="content">
          Panel 3. 
          <br/>
          <button type='button' id='disable-steps'>Disable steps 1 & 2</button> 
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <Hello/>,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Comment: Using Jquery in conjunction with a React framework is a bad idea. 1. Because you can do everything you want using pure JS/ES6 and you'll not have to load two libs

Comment: It makes sense when using something like Wordpress